# How to use DIG to get full DNS info?

Tags: linux, dig

How can I use DIG in one single command to get as much info on a domain name as possible,. including:

- Subdomans
- CNAME entries
- A Records
- TTL

Is this possible with one single command? How can you use dig to find out the most amount of information about a domain in one swift sweep?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a zone-transfer (see dig manual) but nowadays many DNS servers won't allow zone-transfers to unauthenticated clients (that are not configured DNS secondaries).

---

Update

If using BIND for DNS service add

```
allow-transfer {192.168.0.3;};
```

to the `options` clause in `/etc/named.conf` (or chrooted equivalent)

After restarting named, 192.168.0.3 should be able to perform zone-transfers using dig.

Comment: Then perhaps I can rephrase --> how can you use dig to find out the most amount of information about a domain in one swift sweep?

Comment: @RD: If you can persuade the domain administrators to allow you to perform zone-transfers, you can use `dig` to obtain full zone-data. Otherwise you cannot list all records for a domain.

Comment: So, what command can I type to get the most amount of info, without speaking to an admin? (FYI: for the purpose of this exercise, I am technically the admin, with root access to the server)

Comment: `sudo cat /var/named/*` ?